# Retain issue with iOS Blocks

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c-blocks, retaincount

Similar things have been asked before, but I was unable to solve my current problem with any of these answers.

Situation:

```
CustomType *Object;
BOOL (^doAverage)(CustomType *, int, int) = ^(CustomType *Trigger, int Total, int Pulse) {
    //Calculate Average from Total and Pulse
    Total /= Pulse;
    [Trigger setValue:Total];
};

Object = [CustomType CreateObject]; //Autoreleased Object
[Object addCallback:^{ return doAverage(Object, 56, 32); }];
[Array addObject:Object];       //Adds to collection.
```

The issue at hand is a retain cycle as you probably already figured.
`Object` keeps a reference to the block in `addCallback`, and the block `doAverage` retains the reference to `Object`.

Using an instance variable is out of the question, because I want to reuse the variable `Object` for multiple objects. (Temporary variable).
Using a local variable results in the retain count.
And using `__block CustomType *Object` doesn't work either, because for whatever reason `Trigger` ends up as nil once the callback is actually called.

Any ideas?

I have a makeshift solution, but it seems rather...hacky.

Comment: Just to point it out, always make objects lowercase, and you are missing a pointer in the first line.

Comment: @NSAddict Thanks for the pointer, I fixed the issue. Regarding the lowercase...why? You see,  I've 'grown up' with C++ and thereby favour the CamelCase notation. (Capital letter with each starting word)

Comment: This is standard in most programming languages. Classes > Starting with upper-case, variables > starting lower-case, it's a lot more readable, because you can call methods on classes and objects.

Comment: @NSAddict Ah, I see. I shall keep it in mind for the future, for now, please bear with me. And thank you.

Comment: oh camel-case is important too, it's just about the first character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, this answer is rather hacky and I'd be very happy if someone could point me in a better direction.
Apparently a primitive datatype in combination with a `__block` variable does the trick, though this is a bit complicated.

```
void *Ptr;                //Variable for Block.
__block CustomType *Obj;  //Function variable, mutable by block.
BOOL (^doAverage)(void *, int, int) = ^(void *Trigger, int Total, int Pulse) {
    CustomType *T = (CustomType *)Trigger;  //Conversion
    //Calculate Average from Total and Pulse
    Total /= Pulse;
    [T setValue:Total];
};

//Convenience method.
CustomObject *(^Add)(CustomObject *) = ^(CustomObject *)NewObject {
    [Array addObject:NewObject];
    Obj = NewObject; //Assigns to the local block-Variable.
    return Obj;
};

Ptr = Add([CustomObject CreateObject]); //Creates the Object, and adds it to the array.
[Obj addCallback:^{ return doAverage(Ptr, 56, 32); }];
```

Since `Ptr` is a primitive type, it will NOT be retained and does not have to be released. At the same time, it assumes the address of the Object in question and thereby doubles as it.

Once the object is released, so is the block with the pointer and everything is good.
Once the block is called, the pointer needs to be cast to the type in question, but that's only a minor problem.

`Add` is optional of course, but I don't like the syntax `Ptr = Obj = [CustomObject CreateObject];`

Comment: this is not even valid code. The `Add` block has a return type, but there is no return in the body

Comment: @newacct I beg your forgiveness. I must have forgotten the return statement while copying the code.

Answer (score 1):

Several things. First, I would like to see your `addCallback:` method. It's possible that you've implemented it incorrectly. For example, if you store a block for use later, you must copy it. If it's incorrect, all bets are off on the rest of the stuff.

> And using __block CustomType *Object doesn't work either, because for
>   whatever reason Trigger ends up as nil once the callback is actually
>   called.

So if it's `nil`, then that means you assigned `nil` to `Object` somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that 'copy' is imperative. Which is why `addCallback` creates an object (a container) saves the reference with `[Block copy]`. And yes, assigning a 'nil' value is well possible. What I want however is a 'non-retained copy of the object' in question, which will be 'lost' once the corresponding object is deallocated.

Comment: @ATaylor: are you doing something like doing the `addCallback` inside a loop, but declared the `__block` variable outside of the loop? If so, then all the blocks will refer to the same `__block` variable, which will cause problems if the value of that variable changes between iterations of the loop. If you are doing something like this, you would want to put the `__block` variable inside the loop

Comment: No, but it's a similar behaviour. I have a list of statements, who all add to the same array, using the same variable. Though this gives me the idea, that an array of `__block`-variables may well be the solution...however this seems awfully complicated for such a simple task...though just now another idea arises. What would happen, if I declared another block named `addWithCallback`, which takes both the object as well as the block in question?

Comment: @ATaylor: try this: 1) temporarily do another copy of the block you pass to `addCallback:` i.e. `addCallback:[[^{ ... } copy] autorelease]` to see if it changes anything, in case you are not copying the block right. 2) get rid of the `__block` on `Object` and add a `__block CustomType *tmp = Object;` *right before* the `addCallback` line, and then change that block from `^{ return doAverage(Object, 56, 32); }` to `^{ return doAverage(tmp, 56, 32); }`. This will guarantee that that block variable is only used by that block.

Answer (score 1):

```
CustomType *Object;
BOOL (^doAverage)(CustomType *, int, int) = ^(CustomType *Trigger, int Total, int Pulse) {
//Calculate Average from Total and Pulse
Total /= Pulse;
[Trigger setValue:Total];
};

Object = [CustomType CreateObject]; //Autoreleased Object
[Object addCallback:^{ return doAverage(Object, 56, 32); }];
```

Taylor said -> "What I want however is a 'non-retained copy of the object' in question, which will be 'lost' once the corresponding object is deallocated."

This code doesn't seem to cause a retain-cyle unless you use copy on or inside of addCallback([^{}copy]);..

Where is it exactly the copy is used in your code? Inside of addCallback? if this is like:

```
addCallback(o) {

o = [o copy];
o();

then do a [o release]; when you done with a block object.. do not release it in dealloc()
}
```

if you have never used copy anywhere, nothing to be worried about.. It all happens in the stack that means no retain cyles at all unless it is not a global one!

In case there is a retail-cyle, do not use __block __weak etc instead do release whatever object it is in the end of the block.. and bear in mind that no copy no retain cycle..

Comment: I am using 'copy' in `addCallback` though, simply because otherwise the block would be deallocated before I use it. Though I guess a 'one-shot' callback would probably do the trick. (Use once and release right afterwards). Thank you for your input.

Comment: so using copy within your callback is the right form of doing it.. copy it, call it and release the block when you are done that will release the Object right away.. Where did you see a retain cycle in this scheme is not clear to me? It is not the runtime what creates retain cyles but the designer/coder.. Release "Object' after adding it to the callback and use dispatch_async(0,{ block(); [block release]}); to see the result it will even work without copying it if it is a on the fly operation (not persistent).. ultimate solution to retain cycles the blocks do is intermediate obj, thnx

Comment: Yeah, that's the point. I didn't release it right after use, but when I was done with the object that contained the callback, which was retained by the block...and meh, computers...if only they did what I want them to do, instead of what I tell them to do, right? :)

Answer (score 0):

If your deployment target is at least iOS 5 (or OS X 10.7), you can use "zeroing weak references":

```
CustomType *object = [CustomType makeObject];
__weak CustomType *weakObject = object;
[object addCallback:^{
    CustomType *strongObject = weakObject;
    if (strongObject)
        return doAverage(weakObject, 56, 32);
    else
        return 0;
}];
```

(I have used a `makeObject` instead of `CreateObject` for the name of the "factory method", because methods with "create" in their name are expected to return a (+1) retain count object, not an autoreleased object.)

The `__weak` reference does not increment the retain count, therefore no retain cycle is created. If the `object` is destroyed because the last strong reference to it is gone, then `weakSelf` is set to `nil`. Inside the block a strong reference is created, which either points to the object, if it still exists, or is `nil`, if it does not exist anymore.

If I understand you code correctly, the callback will not be called if the object has been released. In that case a `__unsafe_unretained` reference is sufficient (which works also on iOS 4):

```
CustomType *object = [CustomType makeObject];
__unsafe_unretained CustomType *unsafeObject = object;
[object addCallback:^{
    return doAverage(unsafeObject, 56, 32);
}];
```

Comment: assuming he's using ARC, that is

Comment: @newacct: Yes, I have assumed that. __unsafe_unretained is available without ARC, but would probably not help here.

Comment: `__unsafe_unretained` here will not do what you want under MRC. It will still be retained. You need `__block` under MRC instead.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using ARC. I like to keep my stuff 'manual' and 'under control'. (Plus, I'd need to refactor the entire code if I was to use ARC now)

Comment: @ATaylor: Them my answer will probably not help. I am so used to ARC that I did not think of MRC when trying to solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

Try declaring the Object as

```
__weak CustomType *Object
```

Comment: XCode throws me a warning: `__weak attribute cannot be specified on an automatic variable`.

Comment: This will release the object as soon at it has been assigned.
Or because it's an autoreleased object, as soon as it has been autoreleased.